# I can't access my account on stackoverflowforteams.com

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, login

Every time I try to log in, I receive this error screen:

[image: "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"]

I already tried to change my password, but nothing has changed.

If I try to log in with my Google account (the same email) the error is different:

> There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again.

[image: There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again.]

It's very bad, because just can't use my account.

Comment: It seems like they've released broken code just before the holidays. I created a new team and then tried to link my existing SO account to it and now I'm locked out of the admin account. I was only looking to evaluate it so I'm not sure if I will bother jumping through the support hoops.

Comment: @SteveDowling Are you seeing the same errors as are shown in the screenshots in this question? If it's a general software issue, then we can indicate to staff that this is an issue to look at. If it's an issue that's specific to the OP's account and/or your account, then moderators doing anything here is, literally, a waste of time, because the process requires SE Staff to have a more secure conversation with the user, which can only begin with a support ticket and/or a "Contact Us" ticket.

Comment: SO Staff (when you look at this question): I've added a [tag:status-review] tag to this, because it looks like there's at least two people, and potentially more, that have similar problems. It's currently unclear if the issue is something specific to the user's accounts, or if the issue is a software problem. It seemed like it might be a good idea to get it on your radar, in case it's a software issue.

Comment: @Makyen, yes, I'm getting the same errors. It worked initially and I made the mistake of trying to connect my original SO account to the team and it locked me out of the admin account that I created with my company email and I just get the errors above now.

Answer (score 3):

##### Are you sure you have an account there?

Are you sure you created an account on [stackoverflowteams.com](https://stackoverflowteams.com/)? If you haven't explicitly created an account on stackoverflowteams.com *after* at least one of your teams was moved to that domain, then you don't have an account there and need to create one. An account on stackoverflowteams.com will not be automatically created from an existing Stack Overflow account, even if that account was previously connected to your Team. You can have the system create an account on stackoverflowteams.com from your Stack Overflow account, but you need to manually initiate that creation.

##### Open a support ticket at https://s.tk/support

If you have created an account on stackoverflowteams.com using the login method you are trying, then open a support ticket at the [Stack Overflow for Teams support portal](https://s.tk/support). Opening a support ticket will initiate the process of getting help from Stack Overflow staff, who are the only ones who can help you with such account issues.

Alternately, you could use the ["Contact Us" link](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact) at the bottom of every Stack Exchange page. However, the support portal linked in the prior paragraph is the primary support contact method for Stack Overflow for Teams.

##### There's likely extra delay for support in late December

Because you are having this problem late in December, please be aware that the company substantially reduces operations during this period of the year. While I'd expect that Stack Overflow will continue to provide reasonably rapid support for Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise and Business plan customers, which plans come with a higher level of support, I suspect that support for Free and Basic plans may be delayed, potentially until Stack Overflow returns to their normal operations level in January.